# What happens when ToArray() is called on IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble understanding what happens when a ToArray() is called on an IEnumerable. I've always assumed that only the references are copied.

I would expect the output here to be:
true
true

But instead I get
true
false

What is going on here?

```
class One {
    public bool Foo { get; set; }
}

class Two
{
    public bool Foo { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var collection1 = new[] { new One(), new One() };

    IEnumerable<Two> stuff = Convert(collection1);

    var firstOne = stuff.First();

    firstOne.Foo = true;

    Console.WriteLine (firstOne.Foo);

    var array = stuff.ToArray();

    Console.WriteLine (array[0].Foo);
}

IEnumerable<Two> Convert(IEnumerable<One> col1) {

    return
        from c in col1
        select new Two() {
            Foo = c.Foo
        };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the following. When the line

```
var firstOne = stuff.First();
```

is executed, the collection `collection1` is iterated and a new instance of `Two` is returned. When the line

```
var array = stuff.ToArray();
```

is executed, the collection `collection` is iterated AGAIN and new instances of `Two` are returned, including a new instance for the first element of the collection. In particular, this is a different instance than `firstOne`. Therefore, it will be the case that `Object.ReferenceEquals(firstOne, array[0])` is `false` (note that as written, Object.ReferenceEquals(stuff.First(), stuff.First()) would be `false`). This is the cause of the issue that you are seeing.

To get around this, you should say

```
IEnumerable<Two> stuff = Convert(collection1).ToList();
```

or

```
IEnumerable<Two> Convert(IEnumerable<One> col1) {
    return col1.Select(x => new Two { Foo = x.Foo}).ToList();
}
```

so that either way, `collection1` is iterated exactly once and then `Object.ReferenceEquals(firstOne, array[0])` will be `true`.

Comment: To be clear, the problem is because of the combination of re-iteration AND the creation of new objects upon each enumeration.  If the enumeration returned the original objects - without creating new instances - then the re-iteration would still retrieve the original, updated object.

Answer (score 4):

`.ToArray()` is red herring here. In your `Convert` function, you are creating an entirely unrelated instance of `Two` and setting its property to a *boolean value* (which is *not* a reference type) you take from the `One` instance.  Any changes to the newly created instance of `Two` will **not** affect the `One` instance.  They are not related in any ways.

If your `Convert` did this:

```
IEnumerable<One> Convert(IEnumerable<One> input) {
   return from i in input
          select i;
}
```

you'd get the result you expected.

Comment: He's actually only working on the converted list, in this case the class One doesn't have any impact on it

Comment: @Rob: `One` is a reference type. In my version of `Convert`, there's no `new One { .. }`.  It just returns a reference to the same instance.

Comment: I understand that, however the issue is not with the convert function. He's setting the Foo property on the returned collection, not on the original collection. If he removed the One class, and ran the same code without the convert (just create a collection of Two, the same issue occurs).

Comment: @Rob - No.  There are two instances because of the `new` keyword in the `Convert` method.  Remove that keyword, as Mehrdad has done, and then there are no longer two instances - both the original and the returned point to the same instance.

Comment: Yes, there are two instances. However, this has no impact whatsoever on the issue he's encountering. He's deliberately converting One to Two, but he's not checking the wrong values.

Comment: @Rob The OP's expectation is that since One and Two are reference types, the `Foo` property on the `Two` instance should affect the `Foo` property of the original `One` instance and attributes it to `.ToArray()`. I'm demonstrating that the cause is not `ToArray`; it's `new`. Your point?